# django Queryset with year(date) = '2010'

Tags: python, sql, django, django-queryset

I'm trying to build this query

```
select * from m_orders where year(order_date) = '2010'
```

the field order_date is a DateTime field. I just don't want to use raw sql queries here. Is it even possible to use e.g. MySQL functions in django quersets?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can achieve this without using raw SQL. Use the built in `__` mechanism instead (see the [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters) for more details). Something like this:

```
MyOrder.objects.filter(order_date__year = 2010)
```

Answer (score 6):

you can use django's builtin query API for this. no need for any vendor specific code or raw SQL.

it would probably look something like this:

```
Orders.objects.filter(order_date__year=2010)
```

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/